# Removing some text in a file using the terminal

Tags: linux, bash

I have a text file consisting of multiple lines like:

```
Blah blah blah Get_Rid_of_this
Blah blah blah blah blah blah
blah blah blah blah the end
```

For some reason, I need to remove the "Get_Rid_of_this" part. Please don't ask me to just remove the Get_Rid_of_this part manually, it's kinda complicated.

I was thinking of using the head command to get the first line and then use sed or something to remove that part, but how do I save the file back?

Can somebody help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this `sed` command for removing `Get_Rid_of_this` words from your input file,

```
sed -i 's/Get_Rid_of_this//g' input
```

Comment: i think he want `sed -i '1s/Get_Rid_of_this//g' input`

Comment: yeah sorry for that, even I too didn't noticed @qqibrow

Comment: what does 1s mean @AvinashRaj? Does that mean the first occurence?

Comment: it will do the replacement only on the first line.. Not first occurrence.